# Advice on how to copy events in users' own calendars via google API

Tags: google-calendar-api

#### Context

I have a public calendar containing events for course lectures. A course can have multiple lectures every week and continues for several weeks. Of course I have multiple courses.

#### What I want

Users to be able to opt-in and copy the existing events for a single course from the public calendar to their own. Ideally their calendars should update automatically, if events that have been copied were to change in the public one.

#### Thoughts

I am mostly interested in how am I supposed to handle a foreign calendar. Obviously users have to give their own permission, but I have no idea how to start. Suggested approach would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what comes to mind, as an abstract solution flow:

1. My events have to be marked with some sort of **tag**, identifying the course they belong to.
2. When users want to copy a course's events they would to to the course page and click a button, which would prompt them to give permission to their calendar.
3. A script would execute with the given permissions, copying all events with the given course **tag** into the user calendar.
4. If automatic update is not possible (if the public calendar events change), as I expect, a refresh button ask for the same permissions, delete old events and recreate new ones.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @jess I don't have example, because my question is not about malfunctioning code. It am asking about advice on how to approach the situation. I will work out the technicalities on my own - I can read API docs.